# Summernote HTML Crash

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, summernote

I'm having the following issue with Summernote for BS4.

When I try to set a value for the textarea with a HTML value, seems the constructor fails.

I'm trying with:

`$('#summernote').summernote('pasteHTML', '<?php echo $log ?>');`

and the PHP value of `$log` is something like this:

```
"<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:justify"><span lang="ES-CO" style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;mso-fareast-font-family:
Calibri;mso-ansi-language:ES-CO">También se atiende de manera escrita, dando
respuesta a los oficios radicados en la secretaria para oportuna firma del
secretario de despacho.<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="ES-CO">&nbsp;</span></p><table class="MsoTableGrid" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border: none;">
 <tbody><tr style="mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;height:20.9pt">
  <td width="201" valign="top" style="width:150.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:20.9pt">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:justify"><b><span lang="ES" style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Remitente
  <o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
  </td>
  <td width="193" valign="top" style="width:144.65pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  border-left:none;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:
  solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:20.9pt">
  <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span lang="ES" style="font-size:12.0pt;
  font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">fecha<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
  </td>
  <td width="194" valign="top" style="width:145.85pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  border-left:none;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:
  solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:20.9pt">
  <p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align:justify"><b><span lang="ES" style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Asunto&nbsp; <o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:1;height:21.3pt">
  <td width="201" valign="top" style="width:150.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  border-top:none;mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:21.3pt">
  <p class="MsoNoSpacing" style="text-align:justify"><span lang="ES-CO" style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Juan Jacobo Díaz Torres <o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>
  <td width="193" valign="top" style="width:144.65pt;border-top:none;border-left:
  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:21.3pt">
  <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span lang="ES-CO" style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;mso-fareast-font-family:Verdana;
  mso-ansi-language:ES-CO;mso-fareast-language:EN-US">5 agosto 2020<o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>
  <td width="194" valign="top" style="width:145.85pt;border-top:none;border-left:
  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:21.3pt">
  <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="ES-CO" style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;
  mso-fareast-font-family:Verdana;mso-ansi-language:ES-CO;mso-fareast-language:
  EN-US">Entrega resolución<o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:2;height:21.3pt">
  <td width="201" valign="top" style="width:150.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  border-top:none;mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:21.3pt">
  <p class="MsoNoSpacing" style="text-align:justify"><span lang="ES-CO" style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">José Uriel Quevedo <o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>
  <td width="193" valign="top" style="width:144.65pt;border-top:none;border-left:
  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:21.3pt">
  <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span lang="ES-CO" style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;mso-fareast-font-family:Verdana;
  mso-ansi-language:ES-CO;mso-fareast-language:EN-US">5 agosto 2020<o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>
  <td width="194" valign="top" style="width:145.85pt;border-top:none;border-left:
  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:21.3pt">
  <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="ES-CO" style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;
  mso-fareast-font-family:Verdana;mso-ansi-language:ES-CO;mso-fareast-language:
  EN-US">Entrega resolución <o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:3;height:21.3pt">
  <td width="201" valign="top" style="width:150.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  border-top:none;mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:21.3pt">
  <p class="MsoNoSpacing" style="text-align:justify"><span lang="ES" style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;mso-ansi-language:ES">Héctor Julián
  diez <o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>
  <td width="193" valign="top" style="width:144.65pt;border-top:none;border-left:
  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:21.3pt">
  <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span lang="ES-CO" style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;mso-fareast-font-family:Verdana;
  mso-ansi-language:ES-CO;mso-fareast-language:EN-US">10 agosto 2020<o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>
  <td width="194" valign="top" style="width:145.85pt;border-top:none;border-left:
  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:21.3pt">
  <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="ES-CO" style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;
  mso-fareast-font-family:Verdana;mso-ansi-language:ES-CO;mso-fareast-language:
  EN-US">Solicitud matricula inmobiliarias <o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:4;height:21.3pt">
  <td width="201" valign="top" style="width:150.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  border-top:none;mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:21.3pt">
  <p class="MsoNoSpacing" style="text-align:justify"><span lang="ES-CO" style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Noremberg calderón <o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>
  <td width="193" valign="top" style="width:144.65pt;border-top:none;border-left:
  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:21.3pt">
  <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span lang="ES-CO" style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;mso-fareast-font-family:Verdana;
  mso-ansi-language:ES-CO;mso-fareast-language:EN-US">12 agosto 2020<o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>
  <td width="194" valign="top" style="width:145.85pt;border-top:none;border-left:
  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:21.3pt">
  <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="ES-CO" style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;
  mso-fareast-font-family:Verdana;mso-ansi-language:ES-CO;mso-fareast-language:
  EN-US">Copia &nbsp;de escrituras publicas <o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:5;height:21.3pt">
  <td width="201" valign="top" style="width:150.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  border-top:none;mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:21.3pt">
  <p class="MsoNoSpacing" style="text-align:justify"><span lang="ES-CO" style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Martha Eliana Bustamante <o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>
  <td width="193" valign="top" style="width:144.65pt;border-top:none;border-left:
  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:21.3pt">
  <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span lang="ES-CO" style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;mso-fareast-font-family:Verdana;
  mso-ansi-language:ES-CO;mso-fareast-language:EN-US">18 agosto 2020<o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>
  <td width="194" valign="top" style="width:145.85pt;border-top:none;border-left:
  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:21.3pt">
  <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="ES-CO" style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;
  mso-fareast-font-family:Verdana;mso-ansi-language:ES-CO;mso-fareast-language:
  EN-US">Información &nbsp;beneficios de
  vivienda<o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:6;height:21.3pt">
  <td width="201" valign="top" style="width:150.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  border-top:none;mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:21.3pt">
  <p class="MsoNoSpacing" style="text-align:justify"><span lang="ES-CO" style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">Luz Eddy López <o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>
  <td width="193" valign="top" style="width:144.65pt;border-top:none;border-left:
  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:21.3pt">
  <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span lang="ES-CO" style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;mso-fareast-font-family:Verdana;
  mso-ansi-language:ES-CO;mso-fareast-language:EN-US">18 agosto 2020<o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>
  <td width="194" valign="top" style="width:145.85pt;border-top:none;border-left:
  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:21.3pt">
  <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="ES-CO" style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;
  mso-fareast-font-family:Verdana;mso-ansi-language:ES-CO;mso-fareast-language:
  EN-US">Proceso de legalización <o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:7;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes;height:21.3pt">
  <td width="201" valign="top" style="width:150.9pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  border-top:none;mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:21.3pt">
  <p class="MsoNoSpacing" style="text-align:justify"><span lang="ES" style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;mso-ansi-language:ES">Héctor Julián
  diez <o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>
  <td width="193" valign="top" style="width:144.65pt;border-top:none;border-left:
  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:21.3pt">
  <p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span lang="ES-CO" style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;mso-fareast-font-family:Verdana;
  mso-ansi-language:ES-CO;mso-fareast-language:EN-US">20 agosto 2020<o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>
  <td width="194" valign="top" style="width:145.85pt;border-top:none;border-left:
  none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  mso-border-top-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;
  mso-border-alt:solid windowtext .5pt;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;height:21.3pt">
  <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="ES-CO" style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;
  mso-fareast-font-family:Verdana;mso-ansi-language:ES-CO;mso-fareast-language:
  EN-US">Solicitud carencia registral<o:p></o:p></span></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table><p>
```

It happens when I try to save a copy/pasted text form Word, or some complex enriched text, with tables etc.. and I Try to save that HTML result to a variable in PHP and then to MySQL.

Then try to set that value previously saved on the variable as value in the summernote, it crashes !

It is how it is loaded when I try to set the HTML.

[Here is how it looks, as crashed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEIk8.png)

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"? Are you getting a JS error (check your browser's debug tools by pressing F12)? Are you getting a PHP error (check the logs on your server)? Is it just not displaying how you expect (check the HTML source)?

Comment: I mean the textarea is not being drawed, it is as I showed in the early post